# How do I merge a branch into master that is behind master?

Tags: git, gitlab

Here is the situation:

We had a working master branch (M)

We created a branch off master and made changes (A)

We merged A into master (M2)

A had some issues so we broke master

We reverted master resulting in M3 which is identical to M

We made changes on A branch resulting in A2.

We want to merge A2 into master but we are unable to merge because A2 is several commits behind master (M3).

We basically want to make A2 master, but right now the only path forward we see is remaking all our changes that we made in A and A2 into a new branch off master.

We're using GitLab if that helps in providing an easy solution.

Comment: You can cherry pick the merges you want from A2 into Master see https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick

Answer (score 0):

Being a few commits behind normally isn't a problem.
You can simply check out master `git checkout master`,
and then merge A2 into master `git merge A2`. If there are merge conflicts, you'll need to resolve these before completing the merge.

Another option is to update the A2 with the changes in master prior to merging it into master.
You would first checkout A2, then either `git merge master` or `git rebase master`, fix conflicts if there are any, and then checkout master and merge A2 (or A3, if you will) into master.

*Edit*
If you *really* want to just make A2 master, you can do exactly that by checking out master, `git reset --hard A2` and force push `git push --force-with-lease`.
However, this is generally discouraged as you would be changing the history of master. If you're working alone on one computer I'd say it's ok, but if you are several developers this could cause problems.

*Edit 2*
I realized from the below comment that the original changes from A
won't be included in the merge.

Either revert the revert commit master or cherry-pick A into master
to fix that.

Comment: I attempted to merge A2 into master, but it only brought the changes that made A2 different from A. It did not bring all the changes that A made originally, so the merge is complete but A2 and master are still different.

Comment: aah, right. That's a bit tricky. I think I'd try:

* Revert the revert on master: `git revert <hash of revert commit>`

* Merge A2 into master

If that gives you any merge conflicts, I'd try

* Revert the revert on master: `git revert <hash of revert commit>`

* Rebase master into A2

* Merge A2 into master

Comment: Or you could, after merging A2 into master, cherry-pick A into master.

Comment: ^^That's what ended up working for me. Cherry-picking the commits that went into A on a new branch off master, and then merging that branch into master.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out